# Can a positive definite matrix multiplied by a symmetric matrix equal a special orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, rotations, positive-definite

I'm interested in seeing if a symmetric matrix $S$ (which represents scalings/skews in the standard Euclidean scalar product), viewed through the lens of a non Euclidean scalar product (with positive definite Gram matrix $M$), can ever be a special orthogonal matrix $R$ (i.e. a pure rotation in the Euclidean scalar product).

So can $$MS = R$$ ($M$ positive definite, $S$ symmetric, $R$ special orthogonal)
ever be true, if not, is there a simple proof of why not? If so, is there a nice example?

Comment: By considering $(MS)^T(MS)$, it should be straightforward to show that $MS$ is a member of the special orthogonal group if and only if $S$ is invertible, $M=|S|^{-1}\,(=(S^2)^{-1/2})$ and the number of negative eigenvalues of $S$ is even.

Comment: Sure, take $M$ and $S$ to be the identity matrix. Or, take $S = M^{-1}$.

Comment: I'm looking for non-trivial cases but thanks @BenGrossmann, and could you flesh your response out in an answer please @user1551? Is there a non-trivial case to be found there?

Comment: @user1551 it looks like it just creates matrices R which involve reflections in some directions and identity in others, so it's not really a proper 'rotation' but more still a reflection/identity (which is what symmetric matrices intuitively do). Is it easy to prove this is 'the best we can do' here?